# Display attribute from child component to parent in angular 5

Tags: angular5

I have a parent component in which I want to display a title which is an attribute contained on a an object displayed on a child component. I would be something like this:

```
<parent-component>

<h1>{{title_i_want_to_display}}</h1>

<child-component><p>{{object.title}}</p></child-component>

<parent-component>
```

How can I capture that object.title and display it inside my h1 tag on the parent?

Comment: look into inputs and outputs.  They are very handy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

child.component.ts

```
@Output titleEvent = new EventEmiter<string>();
ngOnInit(){
  this.titleEvent.emit(object.title);
}
```

parent.component.ts

```
 public myTitle: string;

 onTitleFetch(title){
    this.myTitle = title;
 }
```

parent.component.html

```
<h1>{{myTitle}}</h1>

<child-component (titleEvent)="onTitleFetch($event)"></child-component>
```

Comment: I just found it myself and It's exacly what you just posted. So i will accept this answer so it may help other people. Thanks.